# Unreal code not compiling in Xcode

Tags: xcode, unreal-engine4

I am trying to build a Unreal Project in Xcode. But I am facing various issues while building it. One of the prominent reason is `Example.h` should be first header included. But I have already included it as a first header. Can someone tell me how to configure Xcode for unreal projects, because it even doesn't recognize the thing that are defined in unreal.
This is the error file.

```
Setting up Mono
Building TanksEditor...
2017-07-09 12:06:52.427 defaults[35773:349710] 
The domain/default pair of (com.apple.dt.Xcode, IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks) does not exist
Running command : Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe TanksEditor Mac Development /Users/rishabhsharma/Documents/Unreal Projects/Tanks/Tanks.uproject
Compiling game modules for hot reload
Parsing headers for TanksEditor
  Running UnrealHeaderTool "/Users/rishabhsharma/Documents/Unreal Projects/Tanks/Tanks.uproject" "/Users/rishabhsharma/Documents/Unreal Projects/Tanks/Intermediate/Build/Mac/TanksEditor/Development/TanksEditor.uhtmanifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors -installed
Reflection code generated for TanksEditor in 10.0231033 seconds
/Users/rishabhsharma/Documents/Unreal Projects/Tanks/Source/Tanks/Tank.cpp(1): error: Expected Tank.h to be first header included.
Build canceled.
Command /Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.16/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Mac/Build.sh failed with exit code 1
```

I tired a lot of things but did'nt find a solution.

Comment: Are you sure that your `Tank.cpp` has first include like: `#include "Tank.h"`?

Answer (score 1):

There no problem with Xcode though the order of your #include does matter so change  Tank.h as the FIRST include then it should work out so #include "Tank.h" should go first and at the top. Please keep me updated so I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

UE build error is buggy, one possible error could be your `xxx.generated.h` isn't the last header included, which it should be.

Comment: It's the last header included. This does'nt solve my error

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem in Xcode. The "tank.h" header file missing in Tank.cpp.
It should be included at the top of your file.